# C++ Runtime Terminates std::out_of_range

Tags: c++, c++11, encryption, crash

The program's supposed to ask the user 3 options:

1 for Encryption
2 for Decryption
3 to Exit

For Encryption first step is to ask for a plain text to be encrypted, the program gets past that.

Next step is to ask for the Encryption/Decryption code, when I put in something that's where the error comes up

[image: From Code Blocks 16.01]

Here's the full code:

```
#include bits/stdc++.h

#include stdio.h 


using namespace std;

void encrypt001();

void decrypt001();


string yes;

string inname;

string key;

string alphabets="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

int size=0;

int y;

int main()

{

    int useroption;

    do

    {
        cout<<"*****ENIGMA****"<<endl;
        cout<<"[1] - Encrypt"<<endl;
        cout<<"[2] - Decrypt"<<endl;
        cout<<"[3] - Exit"<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter Choice:"<<endl;
        cin>>useroption;

        switch (useroption)
        {
            case 1:
                encrypt001();
                break;
            case 2:
                decrypt001();
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"Exit"<<endl;
                break;



        }

    }


    while (useroption!=3);

}



void encrypt001()


{


    cout<<"*****ENCRYPTION******"<<endl;


    string encrypt;

    string ekey;
    cin.ignore();

    cout<<"Enter Plain Text To Encrypt:"<<endl;
    getline(cin,encrypt);
    cout<<"Enter Encryption Key:"<<endl;
    cin>>ekey;

    int elen=encrypt.length();
    int ekeylen=ekey.length();
    int letterslen=alphabets.length();
    int num;

    int y=0;

    for (int x=0; x<elen; x++)
    {
        for (int h=0; h<letterslen; h++)
        {
            if (ekey.at(y)==alphabets[h])
            {
                num=h;
            }
        }


    int num1=0;
    int num2=0;

    string space;
    space=encrypt.at(x);

    if (space==" ")
    {
        continue;
    }

    for (int j=0; j<letterslen; j++)
    {
        if (encrypt[x]==alphabets[j])
        {
            num1=j;
        }
    }
    num2=num+num1;

    if (num2>25)
    {
        num2=num2-26;
    }

    string letterrep;
    letterrep=alphabets.at(num2);
    encrypt.replace(x, 1, letterrep);

    y++;

    if (y>ekeylen)
    {
        y=0;
    }
    }
    cout<<"Encrypted Cipher Text:"<<encrypt<<endl;
    cout<<"Save To File? (y/n)"<<endl;
    cin>>yes;

    if (yes=="y")
    {
        cout<<"Enter File Name:"<<endl;
        cin>>inname;
        cout<<inname<<".txt saved succcessfully."<<endl;        
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Proceed"<<endl;
    }
}

void decrypt001()
{
    cout<<"*****DECRYPTION*****"<<endl;

    string decrypt;
    string dkey;
    string output;
    cin.ignore();

    cout<<"Enter Cipher Text to Decrypt:"<<endl;
    getline(cin, decrypt);
    cout<<"Enter Decryption Key:"<<endl;
    cin>>dkey;

    int dlen=0;
    int dkeylen=0;

    for (int k=0; k<decrypt.length(); k++)
    {
        if (decrypt[dlen]!=' ')
        {
            output+=((((decrypt[dlen]-97)+26)-(dkey[dkeylen]-97))%26)+97;
            dkeylen++;
            dlen++;
            if (dkeylen==dkey.length())
            {
                dkeylen=0;
            }
        }
        else if (decrypt[dlen]==' ')
        {
            output+=" ";
            dlen++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Decrypted Plain Text:"<<output<<endl;

}
```

sorry for the first part formatting, I don't have enough reputation to post multiple links.

The decryption part works just fine.

Error is:

> terminate called std::out_of_range

Comment: Sorry, you won't get the job.

Comment: They found this post on stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace :

```
if (y>ekeylen)
{
    y=0;
}
```

by

```
if (y>=ekeylen)
{
    y=0;
}
```

Comment: Mister, you don't know how much you helped me, I wish I could repay you but I don't have a credit card.

This is exactly what I needed, a miracle, and you sir are a miracle worker.

You should be proud of yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://www.mudkipz.ws) website for more information on vectors in std::func's.

Answer (score 0):

Array and vector indices in C++ run from 0 to size - 1. Thus when you say

```
Int ellen = encrypt.Length
```

And later

```
if (y>ekeylen)
{
    y=0;
}
```

you are trying to access one past the end of the vector encrypt. The at member function then throws an exception of type std::out_of_range that is never caught, and your program terminates because of that.

It looks as though you wanted to find the vector index corresponding to the input for the encryption; you could do that with.                       `std::find and std::distance` as follows:

`num = std::distance(planet.begin(), std::find(encrypt.begin(), encrypt.end(), c0Encrypt));`
this will return `encrypt.size()` if `Encrypt` is not found. However, it would probably be nicer to implement the whole thing with a `std::map.`

STD, LOL

Comment: Sorry did not format correctly.

Comment: A much simpler explanation BELOW.